# SQLAlchemy Connection Pool and Sessions

Tags: python, session, flask, sqlalchemy, connection-pooling

I've recently started using `SQLAlchemy` and am trying to understand how the `connection pool` and `session` work in a `web-application`

I am building an `API` using `flask`.

**__init__.py**

```
engine = create_engine('mysql://username:password@localhost/my_database') 
DBSession = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
```

**views.py**

```
@app.route('/books', methods = ['GET'])
def getBooks():
    session = DBSession()
    returnedBooks = session.query(BOOK).all()
    session.close()

    return something...
```

1) Firstly, if I don't explicitly close my `session` object, will it automatically close after the `request` has been processed?

2) When my app receives multiple `requests`, are the multiple `session` objects being created all linked to the single `engine` object that was created in my `__init__.py` file?

3) Are the `session` objects being created in `view.py` the `connections` that the `connection pool` holds? If so, and these weren't closed, then would new connections have to be made for subsequent requests?

4) Should I be using `dispose()` at some point?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> 1) Firstly, if I don't explicitly close my session object, will it
>   automatically close after the request has been processed?

The garbage collector will eventually* call `__del__` on the session. if the session has not been sorted out by you in some other way, this will probably cause a rollback.  You should usually be doing something like:

```
import contextlib
def myRequestHandler(args):
    with contextlib.closing(DBSession()) as session:
        result = do_stuff(session)
        if neccesary:
            session.commit() 
        else:
            session.rollback()
        return result
```

> 2) When my app receives multiple requests, are the multiple session
>   objects being created all linked to the single engine object that was
>   created in my `__init__.py` file?

yes, [`sessionmaker()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.sessionmaker) holds on to all `Session` configuration.  Using the pattern you've got, you will get a new session for every request, and that's a good thing.

> 3) Are the session objects being created in view.py the connections
>   that the connection pool holds?

[sessions and connections](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_basics.html#what-does-the-session-do) are not the same thing; although each session is ever using one connection at a time, and they return their connection to the pool when they're done with them.

> If so, and these weren't closed, then
>   would new connections have to be made for subsequent requests?

[different pool implementations](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/pooling.html) have different rules, but for most database engines, the default is [`QueuePool`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/pooling.html#sqlalchemy.pool.QueuePool); and it has a default maximum connections of 15.  subsequence requests for additional connections will block or timeout.  Connections are reused when possible, though.

> 4) Should I be using dispose() at some point?

usually not, if you are also using pools and engines and sessions, then any additional resource management outside of committing/rolling back sessions is probably not needed

<sub>*eventually actually means sometime between immediately and never;  don't count on it to do useful work;  Note that your connections will be closed forceably by the OS when your process dies, so using GC for connection management doesn't buy you anything.</sub>